# Changing glow speed in default WPF Button

Tags: wpf, xaml, button

The default WPF button we have in Visual Studio: when mouse hover on it, the button background will glow from grey to blue. The speed is too slow. How to speed up the glowing effect in XAML?

Is there something like below?:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
    <Setter Property="GlowSpeed" Value="0.01" />
</Style>
```

Of course, this property doesn't exist. What property is that suppose to be? Is that some sort of Animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This animation is embedded in the default [`Template`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.template.aspx) of the button, you would need to change the default template which can be found [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773.aspx) (`Default WPF Themes` link).

Comment: as soon as I add ControlTemplate the button disappear. Is that so that I cannot override one specific visual state, and can only rewrite the entire ControlTemplate?

Comment: Exactly, you'd need to copy the existing template and see if you can modify it to your needs.

Comment: Also i think the animation is not only inside the tenmplate but also inside a chrome control which makes it even harder to modify.

Comment: It's WPF, so the button is completely self-drawn and does not rely on the OS anywhere. Case in point: You can get the Aero style on XP, too.